# Variations of $p$-adic Hodge structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

What is the analogue of variations of Hodge structures in $p$-adic Hodge theory? What does Griffiths transversality correspond to? Is there any reference explaining it in detail and containing computations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this account has engaged in a lot of hit-and-run behaviour before being deleted or self-deleting, and there seems little point answering back into a void